# How to make a turtle in python change colors randomly

Tags: python, random, colors, turtle-graphics

```
import turtle
tina = turtle.Turtle()
tina.shape('turtle')
your_name = input("What is your name")

tina.penup()
tina.forward(20)
tina.write("Why, hello there, " + your_name + "!")
tina.backward(20)
tina.color("green")
tina.left(90)
tina.forward(100)
tina.right(90)
tina.pendown()
tina.pencolor("red")
tina.forward(50)
tina.right(50)
tina.forward(50)
tina.right(100)
tina.forward(55)
tina.left(50)
tina.forward(55)
tina.penup()
tina.forward(30)
tina.pendown()
tina.dot(10)
tina.penup()
tina.goto(100, 100)
color = input("What color is the shape")
try:
  if color == ("red"):
    tina.write("Your are correct" + your_name + "!")
    tina.backward(20)
  elif color == ("green" or "Green"):
    tina.write("Sorry, It is actually Red")
    tina.backward(20)
  elif color == ("black" or "Black"):
    tina.write("Sorry, Its is actually Red")
    tina.backward(20)
  elif color == ("purple" or "Purple"):
    tina.write("Sorry, It is actually Red")
    tina.backward(20)
  elif color == ("blue" or "Blue"):
    tina.write("Sorry, It is actually Red")
    tina.backward(20)
except:
  tina.backward(20)
  tina.write("Sorry, but that isn't a color")
  tina.backward(20)
```

This is my code. I would like to know how to make the turtle change colors randomly through out the whole program. It should be changing color every .5 seconds through out the whole program. How should I do this. I tried to import random. This is for a school assignment. Please Help.

Comment: Incidentally, `elif color == ("green" or "Green"):` doesn't do what you want. See [How do I test one variable against multiple values?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15112125/953482) for more information.

Comment: What did you try? And do you want the color to change in random time intervalls, or every .5 seconds? Did you have a look at `while` loops?

Comment: i want it to change every .5 seconds

Comment: Have a look at the `turtle.ontimer()` function and `random.choice()`.

Answer (score 0):

First thing, you should break your code into functions, for example:

```py
def drawShape (myTurtle, turtleColor, shapeColor):
    myTurtle.penup()
    myTurtle.backward(20)
    myTurtle.color(turtleColor)
    myTurtle.left(90)
    myTurtle.forward(100)
    myTurtle.right(90)
    myTurtle.pendown()
    myTurtle.pencolor(shapeColor)
    myTurtle.forward(50)
    myTurtle.right(50)
    myTurtle.forward(50)
    myTurtle.right(100)
    myTurtle.forward(55)
    myTurtle.left(50)
    myTurtle.forward(55)
    myTurtle.penup()
    myTurtle.forward(30)
    myTurtle.pendown()
    myTurtle.dot(10)
    myTurtle.penup()
    myTurtle.goto(100, 100)
```

You can create random numbers using `random`:

```
import random
randomNumber = random.randint(0,5) #created random integer between 0 and 5
```

Now in order to use random for colors, first create a list of colors:

```
myColorList = ["red","green","black","purple","blue","yellow"]
```

and then create a random integer, and use that integer as the index to this list.

When checking the answer, you don't need that many `if`s. Instead, check if `color in myColorList` - and if it's not, you report ***Sorry, but that isn't a color***

To change the turtle color (or in general, to do something) based on a timer, use `turtle.ontimer()` function. When you call `ontimer`, you give it a function and a number representing miliseconds. A very good example is [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=y90OBAAAQBAJ&pg=PT258&lpg=PT258&dq=turtle%20ontimer%20example&source=bl&ots=_1hZ3YpnBR&sig=02qZ9HhcK5tRsV8xjvE2_JgiKCI&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjKjofjuOXbAhUL44MKHdYEAv0Q6AEIeTAH#v=onepage&q=turtle%20ontimer%20example&f=false). In this example you can see they call `ontimer` at the end of the function passed to `ontimer`, so that it keeps happening on and on, instead of just once.